# inject the product information from the variables into the ‘mainBody’ of the page

Tags: jquery, html, xml

Im a beginner to html and jquery so go easy. I have all my product information in my XML file. However i need some advice on how i get the actual product information to show up on each of my different product pages.

Any help is really appreciated. This is what i have so far. How do i get the data variables to show up on the page.

```
            var title = $theProduct.find('title').text();
                    var brand = $theProduct.find('brand').text();
                    var price = $theProduct.find('price').text();
                    var description = $theProduct.find('description').text();
                    var $spec = $theProduct.find('spec');  // This is an XML object containing the child data objects of the 'spec'
                    var specification = [];
                    $spec.children().each(function() {
                        specification[$(this).prop("tagName")] = $(this).text();
                    });
                    // The 'specification' variable is an associative array of the spec child data values that are indexed via the child tag name
                    var imageFilename = $theProduct.find('picture').text();




                     ($id + "" + title + ":" + brand + ":" + price + ":" + description + ":" + imageFilename);

                     for(var key in specification)
                     {
                        console.log(key + ":" + specification[key]);
                     }
                }
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: kind of a vague question but as a basic answer to "How do i get the data variables to show up on the page." try something like $('body').append('<p>'+title+'</p>'); as a basic starting point. .html also works in place of .append depending on what you need. Hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How would i get it to show up on a specific page. As i have got multiple product pages.